# Is this relation in Boyce-Codd's Normal Form?

Tags: database-theory, normal-forms

I thought I understood BCFN until I bumped into this example from my course slides.

- A relation in a library database contains what books are currently borrowed by what users.
- The relation contains the unique ID of the user, their name and the title of the book.
- Different users might share the same name.
- A book can only be borrowed by one user.
- A user can have borrowed more than one book.

An example of this relation could be:

| USER_ID | USER_NAME | BOOK_TITLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| U012 | Charles | Hamlet |
| U034 | Alex | Blue Moon |
| U491 | Diane | Capital |
| U034 | Alex | The Crow |
| U491 | Diane | Economics 2 |
| U012 | Charles | Lost Girl |
| U034 | Alex | Chess basics |
| U012 | Charles | Greek History |
| U491 | Diane | Red Mars |

According to the slide, this relation is in Boyce-Codd's Normal Form,as:

> all functional dependencies of the form $\alpha \rightarrow \beta $
> are either trivial or satisfy that $\alpha$ is a super-key of the
> relation

While it is my understanding that those are the requirements for BCNF, I don't think this relation satisfies them. In particular, the functional dependency `USER_ID` $\rightarrow$ `USER_NAME` is not trivial (as $\beta$ is not a subset of $\alpha$) and $\alpha$ is not a super-key (since by itself we cannot distinguish between entries representing different books borrowed by the same user).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each book has a different title, you are correct in thinking that the relation is not in BCNF.

In fact, the (only) candidate key of the relation is  `Book_title`, so the functional dependency `User_id -> User_name` violates the definition of BCNF. Assuming that a cover of the dependencies are:

```
User_id -> User_name    (each user_id identifies a user with a certain name)
Book_title -> User_id   (each book can be borrowed only by a certain user)
```

a decomposition of the original relation in BCNF is:

```
R1(User_id, User_name)  with candidate key User_id
R2(Book_title, User_id) with candidate key Book_title
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since you start with "Assuming that each book has a different title", I want to ask: isn't that irrelevant to whether the relation is in BCNF? In that case, the candidate key is `(User_id, Book_title)`, and there is still a non-trivial functional dependency `User_id -> User_name`, with `User_id` not being a super-key.

Comment: If a book title is not unique, then two different books with the same title could be borrowed to the same user. In that case there is no candidate key (since `(User_id, Book_title)` is not unique anymore), and in fact the relations is not even a relation, since it could have duplicate rows. So, in that case one should introduce some way of identifying books (for instance the ISBN, or something like that).

Comment: In other words, in that case the problem is that the representation of data with a “relation” (in the correct sense of the data model) is not possible unless we add other attributes (and it is not useful to apply the results of the normalization theory).

Comment: Ah, of course! Thanks for taking the time :)